# Angular - Next Tab Button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tabs

Using this as a base from which to build my tabs

http://jsfiddle.net/jccrosby/eRGT8/light/

```
angular.module('TabsApp', [])
.controller('TabsCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.tabs = [{
        title: 'One',
        url: 'one.tpl.html'
    }, {
        title: 'Two',
        url: 'two.tpl.html'
    }, {
        title: 'Three',
        url: 'three.tpl.html'
}];

$scope.currentTab = 'one.tpl.html';

$scope.onClickTab = function (tab) {
    $scope.currentTab = tab.url;
}

$scope.isActiveTab = function(tabUrl) {
    return tabUrl == $scope.currentTab;
}
}])
```

and currently trying to implement 'Proceed' and 'Go Back' tab buttons, rather than clicking directly on the one you wish to visit.

Was wondering if its possible to implement something like

```
$scope.nextButton = function(tab) {
    $scope.currentTab = $scope.tabs[tab].next.url
}
```

Where I wish to place my next button will not be in

```
ng-repeat='tab in tabs'
```

so unsure as to how to pass in the current tab!

Any help would be much appreciated as always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find an example in the following fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/wyyhpo9n/

Yo ucan still improve it but you get the idea

```
$scope.history = {};
$scope.history.tabs = [];
$scope.history.tabs.push($scope.currentTab);
$scope.history.index = 0;
$scope.history.maxIndex = 0;

$scope.previous = function() {
    if ($scope.history.index <= 0)
        return;
    $scope.history.index--;
    $scope.currentTab = $scope.history.tabs[$scope.history.index];
};
$scope.next = function() {      
    if ($scope.history.index === $scope.history.maxIndex)
       return;
    $scope.history.index++;
    $scope.currentTab = $scope.history.tabs[$scope.history.index];
};
```